# Android - syncronization with mainUi thread

Tags: android

and apologize if this question is asked before..
I am newbie to android.. 
I am using HttpClient to get response from servlet..
and servlet gives me response as JSON Object..
and i am reading this using buffered reader..

for this stuff i am using AsyncTask

Following is the code snippet..

```
public void onClickButtonLogin() {
    button_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
        Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (logInFor.equalsIgnoreCase("Driver")) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText_userName.getText().toString().trim()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(editText_userName.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    doCheckUserAuthentication(editText_userName.getText().toString(), editText_password.getText().toString());
                    if (isUserAuthenticate) {
                        if (loggedInUser.getRollNo() == 2) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TruckingMenuDriverActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid username/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                            editText_userName.setText("");
                            editText_password.setText("");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid username/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                        editText_userName.setText("");
                        editText_password.setText("");
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid username/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    editText_userName.setText("");
                    editText_password.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public void doCheckUserAuthentication(String userName, String password) {
    LoginTask task1 = new LoginTask();
    task1.execute(userName, password);
    /*if(task1.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }*/
}
```

so i am trying to update isUserAuthenticate variable  in onPostExecute but it's not updating..
i am getting false if i first attemt to tun and ture in second..i think may be its thread syncronization problem..but i dont know hot to make main UI thread to wait unitl AnyncTask thread. completes..
so please help me ..what i need to do..
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not waiting for AsyncTask to complete.As an alternative to AsyncTask you can also use following snippet.

```
final String uname = editText_userName.getText().toString()
final String password = editText_password.getText().toString()
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doCheckUserAuthentication(uname, password);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isUserAuthenticate) {
                    if (loggedInUser.getRollNo() == 2) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TruckingMenuDriverActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid username/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                        editText_userName.setText("");
                        editText_password.setText("");
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid username/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    editText_userName.setText("");
                    editText_password.setText("");
                }

            }
        });
    }

}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
    if(isUserAuthenticate){
                            if(loggedInUser.getRollNo() == 2){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TruckingMenuDriverActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid username/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                toast.show();
                                editText_userName.setText("");
                                editText_password.setText(""); 
                            }
                        }else{
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid username/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                            editText_userName.setText("");
                            editText_password.setText(""); 


 }
...
```

inside onPostExecute